# How to disable Operating System(Ubuntu) cache in C program

Tags: c, caching, ubuntu

As far as I know, I can disable OS cache through use open() with O_DIRECT. But How to do that if I am willing to use fopen() instead of open()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think due to the alignment requirements of the `O_DIRECT` flag it's not possible (see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512987/o-direct-flag-not-working)). The f...() - IO family uses an internal buffer to cache IO operation and I don't think that a standard implementation would align that buffer appropriately.

**Edit**

For special purposes, I could think of two non-portable solutions:

1. If you are sure, that your file system doesn't require any special alignment, you could use `fdopen()`:

   ```
   int fd = open( ....., O_WRONLY|O_DIRECT );
   FILE *fp = fdopen( fd, "w" );
   ```
2. If you are working on linux only, using [fopencookie()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) could be a solution:
   Use `cookie` to transort the 'real' fd from `open()` and provide a write function that copies the data to an appropriately aligned buffer and then calls `write()` (I have never used `fopencookie()`, but I think it could be worth trying if using a non-standard GNU extension isn't a NoGo)

In both cases be aware that f-...() I/O functions still do internal buffering so real `write()`s may not occur before you call `fflush()` or `fclose()`

Comment: thanks first. to O_DIRECT, it is OK,[Detail see this page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). Anyway, It doesn't matter. Do you mean that in f...() I/O family there is no way to disable OS cache?

Comment: As I said, disabling OS cache may require special buffer alignment that is not guaranteed by `f...()`

Comment: If you agree withe the explanation, you're free to accept the answer (even if that's not what you wanted to hear :-( )

Comment: OK, I see, I still look forward to hear more concrete answers

Answer (score 0):

After each read/write from the file, you can call [fflush()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) to force the file to dump all user space buffers to lower level buffers. [syncfs()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) may be of use to you to force the kernel to clear all buffers to disk. If you need greater control at a lower level, you will probably just have to use open() instead of fopen().

You may also want to expore available ioctl() calls for your disk and memory devices to see if caching can be disabled systemwide at that level.