# Code that calls ::memalign fails to compile in g++ 4.8

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to compile [this source](https://github.com/krizhanovsky/NatSys-Lab/blob/master/lockfree_rb_q.cc) on GCC 4.8.1:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -D DCACHE1_LINESIZE=64  lockfree_rb_q.cpp -lpthread -o  
lockfree_rb_q.exe
```

But I get a compiler error, which I don't understand:

```
lockfree_rb_q.cpp:171:22: error: '::memalign' has not been declared
   thr_p_ = (ThrPos *)::memalign(getpagesize(), sizeof(ThrPos) * n);
```

The offending line of code is:

```
ptr_array_ = (T **)::memalign(getpagesize(),Q_SIZE * sizeof(void *));
```

I know what `memalign` is and what it is for, but in this source code I don't know why the author added `::` before `memalign`. What purpose does this serve? I have no idea what keywords I can use to search for this information myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::` is the scope resolution operator in C++. It is used here to explicitly call a function in the global namespace.

The error you're getting is because the compiler cannot find a `memalign` function in the global namespace. In order to use it, you need to include the `malloc.h` header file.

Note that it is also a POSIX extension, as far as I'm aware, so it may not be available in your environment. For example, if you're trying to compile the code using MinGW or Microsoft's toolchain, it will not be available. You will need to find a replacement, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563989/366904) or [this one](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/libc/stdlib/malloc/memalign.c).

And from what I read online, it has also been deprecated, even in environments where it is available. That makes good sense, since the memory allocation mechanisms built into all modern operating systems already return aligned memory. You probably don't need it at all.

Comment: Thanks , I am truely in MinGW ,that might be reason that i do include malloc.h still failed to compile !!

Comment: AFAICT, `memalign()` is deprecated, `posix_memalign()` is not. In some cases one might need page aligned memory instead of the default alignment.

Comment: Neither is likely to be supported by MinGW on Windows platforms. If `_aligned_malloc` is available (like it is in Microsoft's C runtime libraries), you can use that. Otherwise, you will need to write your own implementation. It is rather trivial, just a simple wrapper around `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include <malloc.h>` to use `memalign`.

Or `#include <cstdlib>` and use `posix_memalign` instead.

The `::` in `::memalign` tells the compiler to look for the function in the global namespace.