# open() not working with O_DIRECT flag on UBUNTU

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, file-io, disk

I'm trying to open a file with the O_DIRECT flag. On Ubuntu, the program fails with errno 22. I just installed Fedora on the same machine with dual boot, and this exact same code runs there smoothly.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with kernel 3.12.6 and g++ of version 4.8.1 and file system ext4. The Fedora I just installed is version 20 with kernel 3.12.6.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_DIRECT);
    if (filedesc < 0) {
    std::cout << "fail with errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the data journalling ext4 feature enabled. With data being journalled, writes *must* be buffered (think about it), so `O_DIRECT` will fail with `EINVAL`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into it. Will report back.

Comment: Thanks you so much, David! You were right. I created a new partition with ext4, turned off journaling for it, and copied the code over there. It now runs. :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but my filesystem is mounted `data=ordered` (default). According to ext4 documentation, O_DIRECT should work. Can anybody confirm my findings?

Comment: Umm, O_DIRECT means the kernel uses DMA to put the results of your I/O requests directly into your user-space buffer. And it has to be aligned for DMA to work. (512 byte on linux, best to use posix_memalign, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563120/what-does-posix-memalign-memalign-do, see also man 2 open - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html )