# Padding array manually

Tags: c, performance, openmp, xeon-phi

I am trying to understand 9 point stencil's algorithm from [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124104142) , the logic is clear to me , but the calculation of WIDTHP macro is what i am unable to understand, here is the breif code (original code is more than 300 lines length!!):

```
#define PAD64 0
#define WIDTH 5900
#if PAD64
#define WIDTHP ((((WIDTH*sizeof(REAL))+63)/64)*(64/sizeof(REAL)))
#else
#define WIDTHP WIDTH
#endif
#define HEIGHT 10000

REAL *fa = (REAL *)malloc(sizeof(REAL)*WIDTHP*HEIGHT);
REAL *fb = (REAL *)malloc(sizeof(REAL)*WIDTHP*HEIGHT);
```

original array is 5900 X 10000, but if i define PAD64 , the array 
becomes  5915.75 X 10000

Though so far i can guess that the author is trying to align & pad array to 64 byte boundary. But array returned by malloc is usually aligned(& padded) , also, the [posix_memalign gives you a chunk of memory that is guaranteed to have the requested alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563120/what-does-posix-memalign-memalign-do) , we can also use

```
__attribute__((align(64)))
```

what impact does this WIDTHP can make on my code's performance?

Comment: `malloc()` returns memory aligned to a 16-byte boundary, not a 64-byte boundary. The memory `malloc()` returns is **not** "padded".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to put this in as a comment to unwind's answer because he's right. But perhaps I can explain more clearly, albeit in more characters than will fit in a comment.

When I do the math, I get 5904 reals, which is 23616 bytes, which is 396 cache lines for 64 byte cache lines. It is the bytes, rather than the number of elements which must be a multiple of 64.

As to why you want to pad the value of width, lets look at a smaller example. Let's pretend we had a "cache line" that holds 10 letter and that we have an "array" with a width of 8 letters and height of 4. Now since our hypothetical array is in C and C is row major, the array will look something like this:

`AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD`

but what does it look like when it is arranged in cache lines, since those are 10 letters long:

`AAAAAAAABB
BBBBBBCCCC 
CCCCDDDDDD 
DD`

Not good. Only the first row of the array is aligned. But if we pad width by two spaces, we get this in cache:

`AAAAAAAA__
BBBBBBBB__
CCCCCCCC__
DDDDDDDD__`

which is what we want. Now we can have a nested loop like

```
for i = 1 to height
   for j = 1 to width
```

and know that every time we start to work on the j loop, the data we need will be aligned.

Oh, and yes, they really should do something to make sure that the first element of the array is aligned. '**attribute**((align(64)))' won't work because the arrays are being allocated dynamically but they could have used posix_memalign instead of malloc.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that each row of the matrix (or column, if it's treated as a column-major matrix) can be aligned to the start of a new cache line, by adding padding to the end of the line. Exactly what impact this has depends of course a lot on the access pattern, but in general cache-friendliness can be quite important for intensely number-crunching code.

Also, the computation is integer, so the result is certainly not `5915.75`, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand the concept of padding , but your explanation is still not clear to me.This calculation has added additional 15 (5900 + 15 ) & the rows(5915) is neither a multiple of 2 nor is this divisible by 64.

 modern Intel architecture retrieve 64 bytes cache line. 
the nearest multiple **of 64 around 5900 is either 5952 or 5888**, 

If you have some other way of calculating & aligning the WIDTHP , then it would be great if you can explain here!!

Answer (score -1):

The width p calculation is say

```
( Width/64) +1
```

Well rounded for int precision math. I'd give you a better answer except in the SE mobile app it ain't viable to flick between this and the listing

Comment: why +1 ??  if you can then please elaborate, also check out my comment below unwind's answer!

Comment: It's not quite, it's actually width+(63/sizeof REAL). Which is width + nearly 1 or 7.7. What number is sizeof real. Cos all math taka place in int precision there's a rounding down, this 'crazy' formula just controls it better

Comment: @rhubarbdog: Nope. The idiom `(x+(y-1))/y` is used to calculate `ceil(x/y)` when normal division calculates `floor(x/y)`.